# Rubymine 7 Search Application Doesnot return all the result set

Tags: rubymine

I use ruby mine as IDE for ROR Application, after upgrading my Rubymine to 7.0, the full application Search (CTRL + SHIFT + F) doesnot return the full result set.

Any idea why is it so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Found occurrence : 
Check Usage in String Constants, you will find the string o/p results

in unclassified occurrence doesn't find result for that.